# Thread in Form Load lags UI

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I run the code after the form is initialized, it works the way I intended. But, when I load it for the first time in the `form Load` event it lags the UI from drawing for a second. I don't really want to make a splash screen as there's already some UI elements that indicate work is being done.

```
volatile bool ABfired = false;
    public form_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void GetSearchableDataCache()
    {
        this.UIThread(() =>
        {
            ultraActivityIndicator1.AnimationEnabled = true;
            ultraLabel_Status.Text = "Querying SQL...";
        });

        var projids = new List<string>();
        var names = new List<string>();

        ABfired = false;

        Thread A = (new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!ABfired)
            {
            }
            projids = new sql.ProjectIDs(true).Get();
        })
        {
            Name = "Thread A", IsBackground = true
        });
        Thread B = (new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!ABfired)
            {
            }
            names = new sql.names(true).Get();
        })
        {
            Name = "Thread B", IsBackground = true
        });

        Thread AB = (new Thread(() =>
        {
            ABfired = true;
            while (A.IsAlive || B.IsAlive)
            {
            }
            this.UIThread(() =>
            {
                ultraActivityIndicator1.AnimationEnabled = false;
                ultraLabel_Status.Text = "Ready";
            });
        })
        {
            Name = "Thread AB", IsBackground = true
        });

        A.Start();
        B.Start();
        AB.Start();
    }

private void form_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetSearchableDataCache();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your threads are *spinning*, so they each use up an entire CPU core.
That slows the system down dramatically.

You should never wait using a `while` loop like you're doing now.
Instead, wait on a `ManualResetEvent`.

However, you can replace all of that code with much a simpler implementation using `Task`s and no explicit threads.
Using `Task.ContinueWith` will allow you to run a task after the previous one finishes without wasting a thread.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. It turns out the controls I'm using just tend to lag on their own. But I learned something valuable nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - learn programming. A little more than "it works". WHow - that is close to cpu abuse as I ahve ever seen it coming.

> while (!ABfired)

CRAP, especially as ABFired is not locks, not synced. Look up waht a MUTEX does, or ManualResetEvent. You arel ooping a cpu core and dont even make sure you ahve memroy barriers in place so that the thread SEES the changed value.

Second, you can not from those threads go back to the UI without actially doing something like - invoking back to the main thread.

Third, maybe form LAOD is not so much the right place? What about activation of the form?

Fourth, three threads which just play funny games? Do NOT use threads to start, use Tasks, with contiuation - you rebuild that stuff in the worst form I have seen in 20 years.
            { 
            }

Comment: You're right.I'm sorry. A large part of this project is figuring out what I'm doing in this regard.